# Use two arrays for assigning two different values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I know that my question's title looks weird but I didn't know how to ask such a question.

I have two `arrays`

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

And

```
b = ["gf","gdf","gdf"]
```

I have a return statement like this:

```
return {
    options: a.map(value => ({ label: value, value: value }))
};
```

But I want the value inside options to take the values of the `b` array not of the `a` array. How to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could indicate what the expected result is so it is clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass second parameter to `map()` which is index and use it to get elements from `b` array.

```js
var a = [1,2,3], b = ["gf","gdf","gdf"]

var options = a.map(function(value, index) {
 return { label: value, value: b[index] }
})

console.log(options)
```

If you want to use ES6 and arrow functions you can get same result like this.

```js
var a = [1,2,3], b = ["gf","gdf","gdf"]

var options = a.map((v, i) => ({label: v, value: b[i]}))
console.log(options)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a `mapn` function which iterates across multiple arrays, and calls a function whose arguments are taken from each of the arrays:

```js
a = [1,2,3]
b = ["gf","gdf","gdf"]
    
function mapn(arrays, fn) {
  return arrays[0].map((_, i) => fn(...arrays.map(array => array[i])));
}

console.log(mapn([a, b], (label, value) => ({label, value})));
```